# Bind zone file not updated while record is OK when doing an nslookup

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I've set up a zone as a master with allow-updates from a windows `DHCP Server` (authorized on IP only)
when I do a release/renew on a Windows workstation, I can see the PTR record updated/created successfully in a bind in the zone.

if I do a :

```
nslookup IP MYDNSSRVIP
```

I can see the PTR updated/created successfully.

however, when looking at the zone file (e.g., `1.1.1.in-addr.arpa`), the zone file is not updated immediately (if I open it, I can't see the record yet)

does the "datafile" itself take some time to be refreshed? (as I can see the record successfully created when doing a lookup) how is that possible?

or does it mean that something is wrong somewhere in my config and the lookup comes from somewhere else (e.g., a delegation, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic zones have a journal file (`*.jnl`). Recent changes are written there and the zone file is updated only after a:

```
rndc sync
```

Comment: thanks ! will try that (will mark the question as resolved if it works)

Comment: rndc: 'sync' failed: unknown command

Comment: Which version of bind are you using?